# How can I use the public buses in Abu Dhabi from/to the airport and inside the city?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, abu-dhabi

How can I use the public buses in [Abu Dhabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirate_of_Abu_Dhabi) from/to the airport and inside the city?

Answer (score 12):

It turns out buses are a great option to get around in Abu Dhabi: efficient, easy to use, and very inexpensive.

1. You need a Hafilat card. One per passenger.
2. You can buy the card directly at the airport. If you arrive in Terminal A (new terminal), take a right and follow the signs to "bus tickets".
3. There is a counter with a clerk where you can use a credit card. There is also a machine (also with a helpful clerk) that only takes cash. However, there is an [ATM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_teller_machine) right there as well.
4. The card has a fee of 10 AED (USD $2.7) and comes in increments of 10 AEDs. Example: if you take a card for 30 AED you have 20 AED to spend.
5. Rides from/to the city cost 4 AED, rides inside the city are around 2.5 AED. We chose a 30 AED card for a 3-day stay, which was plenty.
6. Buses from the airport are lines A1 and A2. They stop directly outside terminal A. They go every half hour, pretty much all day and night.
7. The best app for exact schedules and tracking stops is Google Maps.
8. The airport buses have a large luggage compartment under the bus. It's automatically opened and closed at every stop. When the bus shows up, just throw your bags in there and hop on.
9. Tap your card when entering the bus. There are card readers at every door. You also tap your card when you exit the bus as well.
10. The buses have TV screens that show mostly advertising but occasionally the next stops in both English and Arabic. You can also track progress easily on [Google Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps).
11. When you are ready to exit, tap your card, get off, grab your bag and you are done.
12. Bus stations are well marked with the bus numbers on it. The buses themselves also have the numbers displayed. For example, bus 94 goes from/to the [Louvre Abu Dhabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvre_Abu_Dhabi).

In our experience, buses were very efficient, clean, safe, easy to use and much cheaper than ride share (which also works fine in Abu Dhabi).